# Git branching strategy for programming exercises?

Tags: git, github

I’m working an extensive tutorial to learn a new software framework. The product is in some flux, so it’s not uncommon for the tutorial to be updated.¹

My needs are:

1. I can keep the original exercises without solutions (normally consisting of a subdirectory of the repo named `problem-NN`, with a `README.md` describing the problem, some data files, a test or two, a code skeleton, and perhaps some utility libraries) pristine;
2. I can track my work in progress on a given exercise in a local branch;
3. When I complete an exercise, I sometimes create a replica branch which I interactively rebase to make the commit history capture the important learning points I may want to review later and remove dead-ends, and which I sometimes upload to GitHub for feedback (but I leave the original WIP commits around just in case I want to refer to them just for my own personal use);
4. Sometimes (but not always) later problems build on the solutions of previous ones, so hard-resetting back to the origin master before beginning each new problem isn’t always possible; and
5. If a change to the origin master happens after I’ve solved a given problem, I need to save my solution at the time I solved it based on the origin’s state at that time—even if I also have to modify it for use in a later problem.

I’ve usually started each new exercise by creating a new branch like, say, `problem-05` based on either `master` (if the exercise has no dependencies) or on `problem-03-solved` (if it has dependencies); when I complete a solution, I create a `problem-05-solved` branch (which, usually, remains an alias for the `problem-05` branch, but gives me a place to diverge if I need to for later problems or for incorporating upstream changes). I create yet another branch, `problem-05-public`, if I want to push a solution up to my fork for feedback.

The biggest issue here (without which this would just be a “create branches however you like” situation) is when these updates to the tutorial are pushed to the upstream origin (often to harmonize the tutorial with a new version of the framework it’s teaching).

The use case is a bit like [exercism.io](https://exercism.io), but while exercism.io is Git-based, it uses its own software to manage the repo checkout, and is organized with different goals in mind.

If there’s a direct analogue to a typical software development lifecycle here, I’m not sure what it is (though it seems to resemble both hotfixing and backporting).

When a new tutorial update comes out, I need to:

1. Merge² the changes into my “unsolved” or pristine branch(es)—which, for now, are just my local `master`;
2. If the changes affect the problem I’m currently working on, *or* a prior problem this problem builds upon, incorporate those changes.

Doing this once is easy—or at least, as easy as possible depending on how hard actually incorporating the newest set of changes into my solutions is. Doing it successive times when later updates come out, however, is harder, since I’d like not to have to duplicate a lot of “porting” I already did to make my solution work with, say, v1.2 of the tutorial when I incorporate the changes in v1.3.

`git-rerere` seems to be applicable here; I already have the rerere-related variables enabled and know how to use it (for simple cases, anyway).

So: how to best organize my branches to be prepared for the origin churn over time?

I know this is a bit of a judgment call without a single “right” answer, but I don’t think it’s so subjective to be off-topic for Stack Overflow—I think there *is* a way to design the branching/merging workflow to minimize work here.

I have later tutorials to work on and I have colleagues who haven’t started this one yet, so while a solution that will be difficult to incorporate at this late stage is suboptimal, it would still be appreciated.

---

¹ I’m learning the software, not writing the tutorial. I’ve contributed things like typo fixes before, so I may have some ability to suggest changes to the tutorial’s repo design. But while I could fork it and maintain a fork (I already *have* a fork, for the purposes of sharing my solutions, but I mean a fork of the unsolved tutorial), you can assume my ability to make changes to the way the tutorial itself is structured is limited.

² When I say “merge” here, I mean it in the English sense; I’m using the word whether the operation is carried out through Git merging, rebasing, or even manually patching.